# I want to be able to collapse and sum values dependent on the gene name

Tags: r, aggregation

I have a table that looks like this: [image]

I want add together all the values for each gene for each column. For example, for LINC01128, it should read:
             ConN1   ConN2   ConN3   StN1   StN2   StN3
LINC01128 :    22      14      37     34     54     67

My table is very long and this would need to be done for all the genes.

Comment: `apply(table,1,sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`, where `df` is your data.frame:

```
df %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)
```

This will sum each column separately (assuming it is numeric), grouped by each gene. Any column that is *not* included in the `group_by` or is not numeric will be dropped at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = aggregate(data,
                by = list(gene),
                FUN = sum)
```